# How to access the beginning of an iterator in a pair in c++

Tags: c++, c++14

I have a pair that has 2 iterators i.e:

```
auto trim = make_pair <std::string::iterator, std::string::iterator>
```

and i'm trying to compare the beginning of the 1st iterator with end of the 2nd iterator.

I came up with this line of code but it's not correct because the program won't compile:

```
if (begin(trim).first == end(trim).second)
```

I have also tried this line of code but it still shows errors

```
if (begin(get<0>(trim)) == end(get<1>(trim)))
```

The error:

> error: no matching function for call to
>   ‘begin(std::pair<__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator >,
>   __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator > >&)’
>
> if (begin(trim).first == end(trim).second)
>
> ```
>           ^
> ```

Complete example:

```
auto func(std::string& str, TrimPredicate p) ->
std::pair<
std::string::iterator,  // typedef to string iterator type
std::string::iterator   // typedef to string iterator type
>
{
// Do stuff and return them as below
return std::make_pair(first_non_ws_iter, last_non_ws_iter);

}

auto func2()-> std::pair<bool, string> {

 auto trimmed_range = func(
                                       line,
                                       [loc](auto char_var)
                                       {
                                        return isspace(char_var, loc);
                                       }
                                       );


  if (begin(trimmed_range).first == end(trimmed_range).second)
            //do something
```

Comment: Iterators don't have begins and ends.

Comment: Can you give a little more context about why you're doing this, perhaps with a short complete example?  Kinda feels like an XY problem.

Comment: @NeilButterworth i'm sorry, new to c++ here, but the prof asked us to write this line of code: `if the trim's "begin" (first) iterator is equal to trims "end" (second) iterator, then loop (i.e., continue).` so i'm really confused now

Comment: @RetiredNinja, ill update the question

Comment: So you would want something like this:  `if (trim.first == trim.second)`

Comment: @RetiredNinja, kk updated

Comment: @NeilButterworth,wait, so what he meant by end is: "the second iterator in a pair" ?

Comment: @Suhaib It would appear so.

Comment: @NeilButterworth, yeah, I guess it makes more sense and it even compiles now. thanks

Comment: @NeilButterworth, sorry to bother again, but i'm trying to understand what you said about iterators not having begin and end. what does the begin in this link http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iterator/begin/ & end [here](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iterator/end/) mean ?

Comment: Functions like begin() and end() return iterators - they can't be applied to iterators. They can be applied to things like strings and STL containers.

Comment: @NeilButterworth, I see

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Iterators work in pairs to designate ranges. A range has a begin and an end. Containers are one of the most common ways of creating ranges; containers have member functions named `begin()` and `end()` that return iterators that point at the beginning and the end, respectively, of the contents of the container. The C++ Standard Library also provides the free functions `std::begin` and `std::end` that can be applied to containers and arrays to get the begin and end iterators.

The comment mentioning the professor's wording suggests that the professor is applying a **convention** that a `std::pair<T,T>` where `T` is an iterator type designates a range, with the first element of the pair being the beginning of the range and the second element being the end. That's fine, but it has no inherent connection to the functions `begin` and `end`.

So the way to get the begin and end iterators from that pair is simply to access the elements of the pair:

```
if (trimmed_range.first == trimmed_range.second)
    // do something
```